# UIView Hide/Show with animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewanimation

My simple goal is to fade animate hiding and showing functions.

```
Button.hidden = YES;
```

Simple enough. However, is it possible to have it fade out rather than just disappearing? It looks rather unprofessional that way.

Answer (score 309, accepted):

In iOS 4 and later, there's a way to do this just using the UIView transition method without needing to import QuartzCore. You can just say:

#### Objective C

```
[UIView transitionWithView:button
                  duration:0.4
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                animations:^{
                     button.hidden = YES;
                }
                completion:NULL];
```

#### Swift

```
UIView.transition(with: button, duration: 0.4, 
                  options: .transitionCrossDissolve, 
                  animations: {
                 self.button.isHidden = false
              })
```

#### Previous Solution

Michail's solution will work, but it's not actually the best approach.

The problem with alpha fading is that sometimes the different overlapping view layers look weird as they fade out. There are some other alternatives using Core Animation. First include the QuartzCore framework in your app and add `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` to your header. Now you can do one of the following:

1. set `button.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;` and then use the alpha animation code that Michail provided in his answer. This will prevent the layers from blending weirdly, but has a slight performance penalty, and can make the button look blurry if it's not aligned exactly on a pixel boundary.

Alternatively:

2. Use the following code to animate the fade instead:

   CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
   animation.type = kCATransitionFade;
   animation.duration = 0.4;
   [button.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:nil];

   button.hidden = YES;

The nice thing about this approach is you can crossfade any property of the button even if they aren't animatable (e.g. the text or image of the button), just set up the transition and then set your properties immediately afterwards.

Comment: @robmathers , I just test your code , above two code  just work when button.hidden = NO, for fade in situation;  have no animation effect for fade out when  button.hidden = YES;

Comment: Seems to be broken in iOS 12.0

Comment: You should use the superview of the thing you are animating as the `transitionWithView` parameter to ensure a successful fade in and out.

Answer (score 174):

UIView animated properties are:

```
- frame
- bounds
- center
- transform
- alpha
- backgroundColor
- contentStretch
```

> Describe in:
>    [Animations](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html)

`isHidden` is not one of them, so as I see it the best way is:

**Swift 4:**

```
func setView(view: UIView, hidden: Bool) {
    UIView.transition(with: view, duration: 0.5, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
        view.isHidden = hidden
    })
}
```

**Objective C:**

```
- (void)setView:(UIView*)view hidden:(BOOL)hidden {
    [UIView transitionWithView:view duration:0.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:^(void){
        [view setHidden:hidden];
    } completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Actually this is the simple and best answer

Comment: While this animates correctly, the UISearchBar I'm trying to display appears in the wrong location until the animation completes and then instantly jumps to the correct position. Any idea?

I'm using Storyboards with Interface Builder and Constraints.

Comment: This code doesn't work ... it directly change the state without animating

Comment: @evya  Only work for fade in  when  hidden = NO ， Not work for fade out,  hidden = YES

Comment: Seems to be broken in iOS 12.0

Answer (score 143):

To fade out:

**Objective-C**

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    button.alpha = 0;
} completion: ^(BOOL finished) {//creates a variable (BOOL) called "finished" that is set to *YES* when animation IS completed.
    button.hidden = finished;//if animation is finished ("finished" == *YES*), then hidden = "finished" ... (aka hidden = *YES*)
}];
```

**Swift 2**

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: {
    button.alpha = 0
}) { (finished) in
    button.hidden = finished
}
```

**Swift 3, 4, 5**

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
    button.alpha = 0
}) { (finished) in
    button.isHidden = finished
}
```

To fade in:

**Objective-C**

```
button.alpha = 0;
button.hidden = NO;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    button.alpha = 1;
}];
```

**Swift 2**

```
button.alpha = 0
button.hidden = false
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3) {
    button.alpha = 1
}
```

**Swift 3, 4, 5**

```
button.alpha = 0
button.isHidden = false
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
    button.alpha = 1
}
```

Comment: using the fade in/out in conjunction with the hidden state solved my problem

Comment: For some reason, animating to hidden=YES worked fine for me, but animating to hidden=NO did nothing, so this combination of animating the alpha and setting the hidden property was helpful.

Comment: I just write a demo , but only hidden = NO , fade in  works,  strange

Answer (score 13):

Use this solution for a smooth fadeOut and fadeIn effects

```
extension UIView {
    func fadeIn(duration: TimeInterval = 0.5, delay: TimeInterval = 0.0, completion: @escaping ((Bool) -> Void) = {(finished: Bool) -> Void in }) {
        self.alpha = 0.0

        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: delay, options: UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseIn, animations: {
            self.isHidden = false
            self.alpha = 1.0
        }, completion: completion)
    }

    func fadeOut(duration: TimeInterval = 0.5, delay: TimeInterval = 0.0, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void = {(finished: Bool) -> Void in }) {
        self.alpha = 1.0

        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: delay, options: UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.isHidden = true
            self.alpha = 0.0
        }, completion: completion)
    }
}
```

usage is as like

```
uielement.fadeIn()
uielement.fadeOut()
```

Thanks

Comment: `fadeOut` works on iOS 13 only if I remove the lines that set `self.isHidden`.

Answer (score 12):

I use this little **Swift 3** extension:

```
extension UIView {

  func fadeIn(duration: TimeInterval = 0.5,
              delay: TimeInterval = 0.0,
              completion: @escaping ((Bool) -> Void) = {(finished: Bool) -> Void in }) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration,
                   delay: delay,
                   options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseIn,
                   animations: {
      self.alpha = 1.0
    }, completion: completion)
  }

  func fadeOut(duration: TimeInterval = 0.5,
               delay: TimeInterval = 0.0,
               completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void = {(finished: Bool) -> Void in }) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration,
                   delay: delay,
                   options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseIn,
                   animations: {
      self.alpha = 0.0
    }, completion: completion)
  }
}
```

Comment: This one actually worked. None of the other solutions seemed to actually make it fade in/out. And the extension is super nice. Well done. :)

Answer (score 10):

**Swift 3**

```
func appearView() {
     self.myView.alpha = 0
     self.myView.isHidden = false

     UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.9, animations: {
         self.myView.alpha = 1
     }, completion: {
         finished in
         self.myView.isHidden = false
     })
}
```

Answer (score 9):

**swift 4.2**

with extension :

```
extension UIView {
func hideWithAnimation(hidden: Bool) {
        UIView.transition(with: self, duration: 0.5, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
            self.isHidden = hidden
        })
    }
}
```

simple method:

```
func setView(view: UIView, hidden: Bool) {
    UIView.transition(with: view, duration: 0.5, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
        view.isHidden = hidden
    })
}
```

Comment: How can I add delay for this one?

Answer (score 7):

the code of @Umair Afzal working fine in swift 5 after some changes

```
 extension UIView {

func fadeIn(duration: TimeInterval = 0.5, delay: TimeInterval = 0.0, completion: @escaping ((Bool) -> Void) = {(finished: Bool) -> Void in }) {
    self.alpha = 0.0

    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: delay, options: UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseIn, animations: {
        self.isHidden = false
        self.alpha = 1.0
    }, completion: completion)
}

func fadeOut(duration: TimeInterval = 0.5, delay: TimeInterval = 0.0, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void = {(finished: Bool) -> Void in }) {
    self.alpha = 1.0

    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: delay, options: UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseIn, animations: {
        self.alpha = 0.0
    }) { (completed) in
        self.isHidden = true
        completion(true)
    }
  }
}
```

for use

```
yourView.fadeOut()
yourView.fadeIn()
```

Comment: giving some hard effect while fadeout, added some better solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57161910/3602846)

Answer (score 6):

I created category for `UIView` for this purpose and implemented a special little bit different concept: `visibility`. The main difference of my solution is that you can call `[view setVisible:NO animated:YES]` and right after that synchronously check `[view visible]` and get correct result. This is pretty simple but extremely useful.

Besides, it is allowed to avoid using "negative boolean logic" (see  [Code Complete, page 269, Use positive boolean variable names](https://books.google.ru/books?id=I-83BAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA268&ots=4EQ6sGrC4q&dq=Code%20Complete%2C%20%22Use%20positive%20boolean%20variable%20names%22&hl=ru&pg=PA268#v=onepage&q&f=false) for more information).

### Swift

`UIView+Visibility.swift`

```
import UIKit


private let UIViewVisibilityShowAnimationKey = "UIViewVisibilityShowAnimationKey"
private let UIViewVisibilityHideAnimationKey = "UIViewVisibilityHideAnimationKey"


private class UIViewAnimationDelegate: NSObject {
    weak var view: UIView?

    dynamic override func animationDidStop(animation: CAAnimation, finished: Bool) {
        guard let view = self.view where finished else {
            return
        }

        view.hidden = !view.visible
        view.removeVisibilityAnimations()
    }
}


extension UIView {

    private func removeVisibilityAnimations() {
        self.layer.removeAnimationForKey(UIViewVisibilityShowAnimationKey)
        self.layer.removeAnimationForKey(UIViewVisibilityHideAnimationKey)
    }

    var visible: Bool {
        get {
            return !self.hidden && self.layer.animationForKey(UIViewVisibilityHideAnimationKey) == nil
        }

        set {
            let visible = newValue

            guard self.visible != visible else {
                return
            }

            let animated = UIView.areAnimationsEnabled()

            self.removeVisibilityAnimations()

            guard animated else {
                self.hidden = !visible
                return
            }

            self.hidden = false

            let delegate = UIViewAnimationDelegate()
            delegate.view = self

            let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
            animation.fromValue = visible ? 0.0 : 1.0
            animation.toValue = visible ? 1.0 : 0.0
            animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
            animation.removedOnCompletion = false
            animation.delegate = delegate

            self.layer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: visible ? UIViewVisibilityShowAnimationKey : UIViewVisibilityHideAnimationKey)
        }
    }

    func setVisible(visible: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        let wereAnimationsEnabled = UIView.areAnimationsEnabled()

        if wereAnimationsEnabled != animated {
            UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(animated)
            defer { UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(!animated) }
        }

        self.visible = visible
    }

}
```

### Objective-C

`UIView+Visibility.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIView (Visibility)

- (BOOL)visible;
- (void)setVisible:(BOOL)visible;
- (void)setVisible:(BOOL)visible animated:(BOOL)animated;

@end
```

`UIView+Visibility.m`

```
#import "UIView+Visibility.h"

NSString *const UIViewVisibilityAnimationKeyShow = @"UIViewVisibilityAnimationKeyShow";
NSString *const UIViewVisibilityAnimationKeyHide = @"UIViewVisibilityAnimationKeyHide";

@implementation UIView (Visibility)

- (BOOL)visible
{
    if (self.hidden || [self.layer animationForKey:UIViewVisibilityAnimationKeyHide]) {
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}

- (void)setVisible:(BOOL)visible
{
    [self setVisible:visible animated:NO];
}

- (void)setVisible:(BOOL)visible animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if (self.visible == visible) {
        return;
    }

    [self.layer removeAnimationForKey:UIViewVisibilityAnimationKeyShow];
    [self.layer removeAnimationForKey:UIViewVisibilityAnimationKeyHide];

    if (!animated) {
        self.alpha = 1.f;
        self.hidden = !visible;
        return;
    }

    self.hidden = NO;

    CGFloat fromAlpha = visible ? 0.f : 1.f;
    CGFloat toAlpha = visible ? 1.f : 0.f;
    NSString *animationKey = visible ? UIViewVisibilityAnimationKeyShow : UIViewVisibilityAnimationKeyHide;

    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
    animation.duration = 0.25;
    animation.fromValue = @(fromAlpha);
    animation.toValue = @(toAlpha);
    animation.delegate = self;
    animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    [self.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:animationKey];
}

#pragma mark - CAAnimationDelegate

- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)animation finished:(BOOL)finished
{
    if ([[self.layer animationForKey:UIViewVisibilityAnimationKeyHide] isEqual:animation]) {
        self.hidden = YES;
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: @valentin shergin Swift version is coming?

Comment: Sure! I have added Swift version.

Comment: Defer block is executed before leaving if scope. I believe it is not how you expect it to behave

Answer (score 5):

Swift 5.0, with generics:

```
func hideViewWithAnimation<T: UIView>(shouldHidden: Bool, objView: T) {
    if shouldHidden == true {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            objView.alpha = 0
        }) { (finished) in
            objView.isHidden = shouldHidden
        }
    } else {
        objView.alpha = 0
        objView.isHidden = shouldHidden
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            objView.alpha = 1
        }
    }
}
```

Use:

```
hideViewWithAnimation(shouldHidden: shouldHidden, objView: itemCountLabelBGView)
hideViewWithAnimation(shouldHidden: shouldHidden, objView: itemCountLabel)
hideViewWithAnimation(shouldHidden: shouldHidden, objView: itemCountButton)
```

Here `itemCountLabelBGView` is a `UIView`, `itemCountLabel` is a `UILabel` & `itemCountButton` is a `UIButton`, So it will work for every view object whose parent class is `UIView`.

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 4**

```
extension UIView {

func fadeIn(duration: TimeInterval = 0.5, delay: TimeInterval = 0.0, completion: @escaping ((Bool) -> Void) = {(finished: Bool) -> Void in }) {
    self.alpha = 0.0

    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: delay, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseIn, animations: {
        self.isHidden = false
        self.alpha = 1.0
    }, completion: completion)
}

func fadeOut(duration: TimeInterval = 0.5, delay: TimeInterval = 0.0, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void = {(finished: Bool) -> Void in }) {
    self.alpha = 1.0

    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: delay, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseIn, animations: {
        self.alpha = 0.0
    }) { (completed) in
        self.isHidden = true
        completion(true)
    }
}
}
```

And to use use it, simple call these functions like:

```
yourView.fadeOut() // this will hide your view with animation
yourView.fadeIn() /// this will show your view with animation
```

Comment: You've just copied @MarkMckelvie`s answer

Comment: There is a difference, he was not hiding the view. And I needed to hide the view as well. So did that and share it.

Comment: Why not just comment on the other answer instead of copying it and passing off as your own?

Answer (score 4):

`isHidden` is an immediate value and you cannot affect an animation on it, instead of this you can use Alpha for hide your view

```
UIView.transition(with: view, duration: 0.5, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
        view.alpha = 0
    })
```

And for showing:

```
UIView.transition(with: view, duration: 0.5, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
      view.alpha = 1
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
func flipViews(fromView: UIView, toView: UIView) {

    toView.frame.origin.y = 0

    self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

    UIView.transition(from: fromView, to: toView, duration: 0.5, options: .transitionFlipFromLeft, completion: { finished in            

        fromView.frame.origin.y = -900

        self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    })


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
 func showView(objView:UIView){

    objView.alpha = 0.0
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        objView.alpha = 0.0
    }, completion: { (completeFadein: Bool) -> Void in
        objView.alpha = 1.0
        let transition = CATransition()
        transition.duration = 0.5
        transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
        transition.type = kCATransitionFade
        objView.layer.add(transition, forKey: nil)
    })
}

func HideView(objView:UIView){

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        objView.alpha = 1.0
    }, completion: { (completeFadein: Bool) -> Void in
        objView.alpha = 0.0
        let transition = CATransition()
        transition.duration = 0.5
        transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
        transition.type = kCATransitionFade
        objView.layer.add(transition, forKey: nil)
    })
}
```

And pass your view name

```
        showView(objView: self.viewSaveCard)
        HideView(objView: self.viewSaveCard)
```

Answer (score 1):

If your view is set to hidden by default or you change the Hidden state which I think you should in many cases, then none of the approaches in this page will give you both FadeIn/FadeOut animation, it will only animate one of these states, the reason is you are setting the Hidden state to false before calling **UIView.animate** method which will cause a sudden visibility and if you only animate the alpha then the object space is still there but it's not visible which will result to some UI issues.

So the best approach is to check first if the view is hidden then set the alpha to 0.0, like this when you set the Hidden state to false you won't see a sudden visibility.

```
func hideViewWithFade(_ view: UIView) {
    if view.isHidden {
        view.alpha = 0.0
    }

    view.isHidden = false

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0.0, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
        view.alpha = view.alpha == 1.0 ? 0.0 : 1.0
    }, completion: { _ in
        view.isHidden = !Bool(truncating: view.alpha as NSNumber)
    })
}
```

Comment: This solves the issue others have asked about where fadeins weren't working. Clever approach.

Answer (score 1):

UIView.transition(with:) function is nice and neat.

Many have posted it but none has noticed there lies a fault will show up only when you run it.

You can transition hidden property to true perfectly, whereas when you attempt to transition it to false, the view will simple disappear suddenly without any animation.

That's because this api only works **within** a view, which means when you transition a view to show, in fact itself shows immediately, only its content animated out gradually.

When you try to hide this view, itself hide right away, makes the animation to its content meaningless.

To solve this, when hiding a view, the transition target should be its parent view instead of the view you want to hide.

```
func transitionView(_ view: UIView?, show: Bool, completion: BoolFunc? = nil) {
    guard let view = view, view.isHidden == show, let parent = view.superview else { return }

    let target: UIView = show ? view : parent
    UIView.transition(with: target, duration: 0.4, options: [.transitionCrossDissolve], animations: {
        view.isHidden = !show
    }, completion: completion)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UIView.transition(with: title3Label, duration: 0.4,
                          options: .transitionCrossDissolve,
                          animations: {
                            self.title3Label.isHidden = !self.title3Label.isHidden
                      })
```

Applying transition on View with some delay gives hide and show effect

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it VERY easily using [Animatics](https://github.com/hip4yes/Animatics) library:

```
//To hide button:
AlphaAnimator(0) ~> button

//to show button
AlphaAnimator(1) ~> button
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution for **Swift 3**. So, I created the function, that hide/unhide view in the right order(when hiding - set alpha to 0 and then isHidden to true; unhiding - first reveal the view and then set it's alpha to 1):

```
func hide(_ hide: Bool) {
    let animations = hide ? { self.alpha = 0 } :
                            { self.isHidden = false }
    let completion: (Bool) -> Void = hide ? { _ in self.isHidden = true } :
                                            { _ in UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, animations: { self.alpha = 1 }) }
    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, animations: animations, completion: completion)
}
```

Comment: Why in `completion` block there's another animation when `hide`is false?

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4 Transition**

```
    UIView.transition(with: view, duration: 3, options: .transitionCurlDown,
                      animations: {
                        // Animations
                        view.isHidden = hidden
    },
                      completion: { finished in
                        // Compeleted
    })
```

If you use the approach for older swift versions you'll get an error :

```
Cannot convert value of type '(_) -> ()' to expected argument type '(() -> Void)?'
```

Useful [reference](https://medium.com/swift-programming/swift-uiview-animation-syntax-sugar-d40448fe1fed).

Comment: does this work with autolayout? similar code isn't animating. the `isHidden` value is rendered instantly (i.e., instantly hiding/showing view).

Answer (score 0):

> This code give an animation like pushing viewController in
>   uinavigation controller...

```
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
 animation.type = kCATransitionPush;
 animation.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight;
 animation.duration = 0.3;
 [_viewAccountName.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:nil];

 _viewAccountName.hidden = true;
```

> Used this for pop animation...

```
 CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
 animation.type = kCATransitionPush;
 animation.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft;
 animation.duration = 0.3;
 [_viewAccountName.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:nil];

 _viewAccountName.hidden = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried some of the exited answers, some only work for one situation, some of them need to add two functions.

**Option 1**

Nothing to do with `view.isHidden`.

```
extension UIView {
    func animate(fadeIn: Bool, withDuration: TimeInterval = 1.0) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: withDuration, delay: 0.0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            self.alpha = fadeIn ? 1.0 : 0.0
        })
    }
}
```

Then pass `isFadeIn` (`true` or `false`)

```
view.animate(fadeIn: isFadeIn)
```

**Option 2**

Don't pass any parameter. It fades in or out according to `isUserInteractionEnabled`. This also suits the situation animate back and forth very well.

```
func animateFadeInOut(withDuration: TimeInterval = 1.0) {
    self.isUserInteractionEnabled = !self.isUserInteractionEnabled
    UIView.animate(withDuration: withDuration, delay: 0.0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
        self.alpha = self.isUserInteractionEnabled ? 1.0 : 0.0
    })
}
```

Then you call

```
yourView.animateFadeInOut()
```

> Why `self.isUserInteractionEnabled` ?
>
> Tried to replace `self.isUserInteractionEnabled` by `self.isHidden`,
>   no luck at all.

That's it. Cost me sometime, hope it helps someone.