# How to hide/show UIView with animation in iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewanimation

I want to show UIView after button pressed with animation,I can show the view but I am unable to hide it again pressed that button.Here is my code to show/hide the view.
To Show the UIView :

```
    sliderView.frame =  CGRectMake(130, 20, 0, 0);
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
    sliderView.frame =  CGRectMake(130, 30, 100, 200);
    }];
```

To Hide the UIView :

```
     [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
     sliderView.frame =  CGRectMake(130, 30, 0, 0);
    }];
```

Using above code view is showing with animation but not hiding.
Does anybody know how to hide it,Please help,Thanks

Comment: The code you posted should shrink the `sliderView` down to nothing. What actually happens now? You don't tell us what the actual problem is.

Comment: How can that code show the view? It shrinks the frame's width and height to 0. Are you sure the code to hide the view is being called?

Comment: Where are you calling each of those methods? Right after each other or with some event? Is sliderView the same object in both calls?

Comment: check you hide action called or not

Comment: you can use the aplha property eg--> <UIViewObject>.alpha = 0;(completely invisible) and <UIViewObject>.alpha = 1;(completely visible)

Comment: @rmaddy and NANNAV Yes,the code to hide the view is being called because I am checking this using flag.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29080894/1442541

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your code works, i have used it. Look code below 
 
.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface StackoverflowTestViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *cautionView;


- (IBAction)btnToggleClick:(id)sender;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btnToggle;
@end
```

.m file:

```
#import "StackoverflowTestViewController.h"

@interface StackoverflowTestViewController ()

@end

@implementation StackoverflowTestViewController

bool isShown = false;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)btnToggleClick:(id)sender {
    if (!isShown) {
        _cautionView.frame =  CGRectMake(130, 20, 0, 0);
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
            _cautionView.frame =  CGRectMake(130, 30, 100, 200);
        }];
        isShown = true;
    } else {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
            _cautionView.frame =  CGRectMake(130, 30, 0, 0);
        }];
        isShown = false;
    }
}
@end
```

Comment: Thanks Binh Lee ,Also I want to add Imageview on that UIView,so can I change the frame of imageview like UIView??

Comment: no problem man, (1).you can add ImageView to that UIView and change frame on that UIView (2) change UIView above with ImageView with no problem

Comment: @BinhLee i am using for your code that _cautionView is animated. i did add two UILabel into that _cautionView. That Label not hide while animate.

Answer (score 6):

```
  -(void)fadeInAnimation:(UIView *)aView {

    CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.type =kCATransitionFade;
    transition.duration = 0.5f;
    transition.delegate = self;
    [aView.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
    }

Add Subview:

     [self.view addsubView:mysubview]; 
     [self fadeInAnimation:self.view];

Remove SubView:

      [mySubView removefromSuperView];   
      [self fadeInAnimation:self.view];
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use alpha property and hidden property of UIView to hide your sliderView. Try the following code:

```
/*To unhide*/
[sliderView setHidden:NO];
sliderView.frame =  CGRectMake(130, 20, 0, 0);
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
    sliderView.frame =  CGRectMake(130, 30, 100, 200);
    sliderView.alpha = 1.0f;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
}];

/*To hide*/
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
    sliderView.frame =  CGRectMake(130, 30, 0, 0);
    [sliderView setAlpha:0.0f];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [sliderView setHidden:YES];
}];
```

Comment: This works for me .. If you are using story board , you can add a uiview & make it's size as you want . If so you can remove the sliderView.frame's CGRectMake values

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
- (IBAction)eventparameter:(id)sender
{
    if ([self.parameterview isHidden])
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"LeftFlip" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.8];
        _parameterview.hidden=NO;
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
        [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown    forView:_parameterview cache:YES];
        [UIView commitAnimations];   
    }
    else
    {
        [UIView transitionWithView:_parameterview
                          duration:0.4
                           options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp
                        animations:NULL
                        completion:NULL];

        [self.parameterview  setHidden:YES]; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply Initial/starting frame of you View is

```
sliderView.frame =  CGRectMake(130, 480, 100, 200);
```

Give tag of your button such like

`myButton.tag = 101;`

And your button method

```
-(void)MyButonMethod:(UIButton *)sender
{
  if(sender.tag == 101)
  {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
         sliderView.frame =  CGRectMake(130, 30, 100, 200);
    }]; 

    sender.tag = 102;
  }
  else
  {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
         sliderView.frame =  CGRectMake(130, 480, 100, 200);
    }];     
    sender.tag = 101;  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:.25];
[sliderView setFrame:CGRectMake(130, 30, 0, 0)];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: These are old and outdated. Apple recommends that you use the block versions (as shown in the original question).