# How to hide image view in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I have image view, if click button talking tom cat will play with animationRepeatCount:2, after this, I want to hide image view. How to hide that image view?

```
    - (IBAction)catBlinkButton:(UIButton *)sender {
    self.imageView.hidden = NO;
    self.imageView.animationDuration = 2;
    self.imageView.animationRepeatCount = 2;
    self.imageView.animationImages = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:
                                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"cat_blink0000.png"],
                                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"cat_blink0001.png"],
                                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"cat_blink0002.png"],
                                      nil];

    [self.imageView startAnimating];

}
```

This is my code...

Comment: use imageview.hidden = yes

Comment: Mr.  karthikeyan  where i need to write that code..

Comment: write this code in last line self.imageView.hidden = YES;

Comment: - (IBAction)catBlinkButton:(UIButton *)sender {
self.imageView.hidden = NO;
self.imageView.animationDuration = 2;
self.imageView.animationRepeatCount = 2;
self.imageView.animationImages = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"cat_blink0000.png"],
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"cat_blink0001.png"],
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"cat_blink0002.png"],
                              nil];

[self.imageView startAnimating];
self.imageView.hidden = YES;
}

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9283270/access-method-after-uiimageview-animation-finish

Comment: already i write this code, if i write like this it's not animating..... why?

Comment: @Lyankar add your imageview in uiview and than try to hide uiiew with animating

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9115854/uiview-hide-show-animate

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can simply use `CATransaction` like:

```
self.imageView.hidden = NO;

[CATransaction begin];

[CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{

    self.imageView.hidden = YES;

}];

self.imageView.animationDuration = 2;
self.imageView.animationRepeatCount = 2;
self.imageView.animationImages = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"cat_blink0000.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"cat_blink0001.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"cat_blink0002.png"],
                                  nil];

[self.imageView startAnimating];

[CATransaction commit];
```

`CATransaction` will dynamically wait for the animation to finish...

Comment: That's really a nice way of doing it. (y)

Comment: 0yeoj, can you please send the code how to play multiple audio (MP3) songs in AVPlayerViewController....

Comment: @Lyankar, what do you mean multiple mp3? Playing simultaneously?

Comment: @Lyankar, ow.. i get it.. you need some customization with that.. you can post another for that one.. don't forget to provide some code you tried so far..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134337/discussion-between-lyankar-and-0yeoj).

Answer (score 2):

You can execute the code after slate on main thread.

```
- (IBAction)catBlinkButton:(UIButton *)sender {

    self.imageView.hidden = NO;
    self.imageView.animationDuration = 2;
    self.imageView.animationRepeatCount = 2;
    self.imageView.animationImages = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:
                                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"cat_blink0000.png"],
                                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"cat_blink0001.png"],
                                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"cat_blink0002.png"],
                                      nil];

    [self.imageView startAnimating];

    // after 2 seconds.
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 2 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        // hide imageview
        self.imageView.hidden = YES;
    });
}
```

Comment: can you please send the code how to play multiple audio (MP3) songs in AVPlayerViewController....

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with UIView's hidden property.
imageView.hidden = true;

Answer (score 1):

```
- (IBAction)catBlinkButton:(UIButton *)sender {
self.imageView.hidden = NO;
self.imageView.animationDuration = 2;
self.imageView.animationRepeatCount = 2;
self.imageView.animationImages = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"cat_blink0000.png"],
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"cat_blink0001.png"],
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"cat_blink0002.png"],
                              nil];

[self.imageView startAnimating];
}
```

Comment: Dishant Rajput, my prog completely not animating if i write code like this

Comment: i also want to know.. Is your image name is correct?