# Using tap gesture recognizer to disable a tip view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Currently, I have question buttons bring up a tip view when pressed.  Now what I want to do is lock the button after it's been pressed, but after you press the screen once the tip view goes away and the button gets re-enabled.  I've figured out to use a tap gesture recognizer, but I don't know where exactly to connect it.  I also don't know how to include the button or tip view in the function.  I'm fairly new to swift, so I apologize if this is common knowledge that I should know.

Answer (score 0):

I'm giving you tips:

- Add button and your tipView on your main view.
- set `hidden=true` for tipView.
- [Add tap gesture and it's method on main view.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28675209/how-to-call-gesture-tap-on-uiview-programmatically-in-swift)
- in Button's action method write code for unhide tipView means here you should write `hidden=false`  for tipView
- Now again write `hidden=true` in tap gesture's method that you added in your code.

This is simple tips that might be helpful for you, here you can [add animation for hide/show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9115854/uiview-hide-show-with-animation) tipView.